# Animating a div in with jQuery and pushing down content below it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am animating in divs in a specific order. I start them all at the top with absolute positioning and `display: none` so they are on top of each other in the same space and invisible. In a specific order determined by something else, I want to fade them in individually and slide down the ones that have already been faded in.

I'm using code that loops through the comments and checks if one is ready to go (by the other metric that is not important). If it is, that is when I want to do this fade in/slide down others thing. Here's how I'm (unsuccessfully) trying to do this:

```
$('#item' + i).fadeIn("slow");
$('#item_' + i).animate({   
    top: '0px'
}, 500);
$('#item_' + i).css('position', 'relative');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the point of absolute positioning, if you have `display: none`? You can make all divs  relatively positioned or remove the position style altogether. Then just grab the div and prepend it to desired container - http://jsfiddle.net/zvc76/1/

```
$("#item" + i).prependTo("#container").show(400);
```

Comment: You're right about absolute positioning being pointless in my example. That's more the result of me trying a bunch of different things one after another. Thanks for the help though, I guess there's always a handy jQuery function to solve things.